# Bluetooth headphones disconnects when I play a certain game

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, bluetooth, gaming

This is not the "my headphones die, my game crashes" or anything like that. My headphones disconnect from my output and don't connect back whenever I'm playing this certain game or window, (FL Studio 20 also does this) and I've updated drivers supported my computer manufacturer, on device manager too, turned off telephony (mic for headphones), and I also forced my desktop or fifine mic to be the default, (even before I still had it as default.) These games don't have voice chat, and games such as Terraria allow me to have my stereo to be on, but others don't work. I've tried it on the most jankiest games like Bloons TD 6 or even ROBLOX. I've yet to figure out the cause, if any additional information is needed, I'll be welcome to give it.

Comment: Try: In *Control Panel > Sound*, Communications Tab, set to "Do nothing" and OK.

Comment: @harrymc It didn't work. Seems like to me I think it's something like either the games files or something. I doubt this is the reason but whenever I play 2D games it works perfectly fine, just when I play 3D games. Weird.

Comment: Try perhaps headphones from another make.

Comment: @harrymc Guess so, hope not, but if anybody has a different solution then I'm up for grabs. May or may not need a new pair of headphones. If I write the problem more clearly or state it more, will it help?

Comment: Perhaps. State the exact models of headphones and computer and add as many details as you can. Search the Event Viewer for information.

Comment: I have the Cowin E7 Stereo, both disabled handsfree. Stereo Microphone, Fifine K678, Computer Model: Alienware R8 (Sorry, my dad thought it was a great idea to get Alienware because apparently I can't build my own as a Computer Science Student). Event Viewer I've checked many times, Windows Audio crashes but this has been happening before this issue. I will also restate the issue in a clearer way.

When I play a game, my Stereo part of my headphones disconnect, except my handsfree stays. It disconnects itself from output and cannot reconnect back til the window is closed.

Comment: Please edit your post rather than stuff everything into one formless comment.